# Simulating noise in OFDM

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, theory, modem, digital

Say I'd like to simulate a certain E_s/N0 in a baseband OFDM MATLAB modem for SER curves.

I randomize 50 QAM symbols with N subcarriers each in frequency domain, add null frequencies (guard bands) to each symbol, perform an IFFT and then add a CP.

Then I convolve the time domain signal with a certain channel impulse response with taps of my choice; I then want to add noise, but I'm not sure about how to normalize it so that it would have the right meaning of E_s/N0 (Energy per **Symbol**) and I'll get the theoretical results.

I get funky results with just MATLAB's *agwn* function with the 'measured' flag.

Answer (score 0):

congratulations for being aware of this! The difference between SNR, E_b/N0 and E_s/N0 is far too often ignored.

The FFT on the OFDM receiver side will take the white noise (a**w**gn) and spread it evenly over all bins.
What you thus see is the constant noise contribution to all symbols, be it CP, guard or information symbol, and is directly derived from N0 (and the FFT length).

The energy of your symbol depends on the QAM you're actually using -- QAM 16 with the same maximum amplitude as a QAM 1024 will have a different average symbol energy.

Since [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering_and_physics) links frequency domain to time domain energy (depending on whether the FFT scales or doesn't with a factor of 1 or 1/N), so this will directly be your symbol energy.

Having both defined E_s and N0, the ratio of these should now be clear.